# Footer is covered by filled margin but only on an iphone

Tags: html, ios, css

My website's footer is covered with solid color when viewed on an iphone 5 in both chrome and safari.  When viewed on an Android tablet it looks fine, as well as in chrome developer on both a desktop and a laptop at various responsive settings.

The footer is position: fixed, height: 200px while the  preceding div is bottom-margin: 200px.  The scroll effect is nice except when the footer gets hidden.

I've searched all over but nothing pertinent seems to come up. I've messed with z-index, margins, padding, background-clip and overflow. Not sure if my attempts failed due to poor implementation or misused css.

[*site link*](http://www.surfing-chef.com).  The solid margin only appears in this example when I view it on my iPhone.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="page">
<section></section>
<header></header>
<div class="site-content"></div>
<footer></footer>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  position: relative;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  clear: both;
}

#page {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

*, ::after, ::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.site-content {
  display: block;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, .6);
  margin-bottom: 200px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid shade(white, 70%);
  min-height: 50vh;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding-top: 1px;
      background: url(https://raw.githubusercontent.com/thoughtbot/refills/master/source/images/textures/grey.png),center no-repeat rgba(0,0,0,.7) scroll;
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,-3px);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,-3px);
  z-index: -3;
}
```

Comment: Fixed. I used breakpoints to change the footer from fixed to relative at the max screen width that an iPhone would be (600px landscape).  My question still stands despite this fix: Why does this only happen on iPhones?